# Print the history for the last 10 Commands on the session on each log in to the shell

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, input-history

I'm trying to print out the last 10 commands on the last session on each login, in the
bash.bashrc. I wrote this:

```
echo "$(history 10)"
```

But it didn't print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash history is only loaded from file after `.bashrc` has completed.

You can force the loading of history and then output what you want by adding the following to your `.bashrc` file:

```
history -r
history 10
```